# DataFrame filter data with string type use like

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
block_name  
['循环经济']
['3D打印']
['再生经济']
```

Now I want get the data with `block_name` contains `'经济'` words.

The result that I want is:

```
block_name  
['循环经济']
['再生经济']
```

And I tried this:

```
df = df[('经济' in df['block_name'])]
```

And this:

```
df = df[(df['block_name'].find('经济') != -1)]
```

But they don't work.

How should I do this result like the SQL's `like "%经济%"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.str.contains()`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['循环经济', '3D打印', '再生经济'], columns=['block_name'])

print df[df['block_name'].str.contains('经济')]
```